# Javascript (node) regex doesn't seem to match start of string

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

im struggling with regular expressions in Javascript, they don't seem to start at the beginning of the string. In a simple example bellow I want to get the file name and then everything after the first colon

```
 //string
 file.text:16:  lots of random text here with goes on for ages

 //regex
 (.?)[:](.*)

 // group 1 returns 't'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
/^([^:]+)[:](.*)/
```

Explaination:

```
^       #Start of string
(       #Start of capturing class #1
  [^:]    #Any character other than :
  +       #One or more of the previous character class
)       #End of capturing class #1
[:]     #One :
(.*)    #Any number of characters other than newline
```

The `?` operator captures zero or one of the previous symbol only.

You could also use string operations instead:

```
str = "file.text:16:";
var n = str.indexOf(":");
var fileName = str.substr(0, n);
var everythingElse = str.substr(n);
```

Comment: so generally I have to put a ^ to say the start of the string?

Comment: @beck Yes, `^` is a special character that means the start of the string.

Comment: great thanks, i've only ever used regular expressions in Java and don't remember needing that.

Comment: You only need it if you need the regex to start matching at the start of the string.

Answer (score 2):

```
/^([^:]+):(.*)/.exec('file.text:16:  lots of random text here with goes on for ages')
```

gives ....

```
["file.text:16:  lots of random text here with goes on for ages", "file.text", "16:  lots of random text here with goes on for ages"]
```

Answer (score 1):

The ? operator returns 0 or 1 matches.  You want the * operator, and you should select everything that isn't a : in the first set

```
  ([^:]*)[:](.*)
```

Answer (score 1):

Non-regexy answer:

```
var a = s.split(":");
```

Then join a[1] and remaining elements.

Or just get the index of the first semicolon and create two strings using that.